# Convert Array in C++ to String

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I know in Java, you can use Arrays.toString() to return a String representation of an Array. Is there a method that serves a similar function in C++?

Comment: what array are you talking about? char arrays are considered as a string (null terminated). Other arrays will depend on if the value type can be converted to a string. Example: integer array can be converted to a string perhaps by iterating over it and using `std::to_string()`, but an array of mutexes or thread objects? probably no need or way

Comment: Read a [good C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) then see a good [C++ reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: *I know in Java, you can use Arrays.toString() to return a String representation of an Array.* -- Do not use Java or any other language as a guide in learning C++.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

C++ is not Java. I recommend reading a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) and to look into some [C++ reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Be aware of various dialects of C++ (e.g. [C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) is not the same as C++17).

Remember that C++ arrays are homogeneous: all array components have the same type. In contrast to Java, C++ does not have a root type like Java `Object` class. But C++ has interesting [standard containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). Be aware of the [rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html). And you could design your program to have your central `class MyRootClass` from which every other `class` inherits.

However, you could easily write some short code to convert an array to a string.

That being said, you could find interesting open source C++ libraries, such as [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/), to ease your work.

You could also (and easily) write your C++ metaprogram generating the C++ code for declaring arrays and emitting code to print or output them, and you might use or improve the [SWIG](http://swig.org/) tool for that.

Read also the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/)), your linker (e.g. GNU [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)) and of your build automation (e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)). If your C++ compiler is GCC, compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) all warnings and debug info, so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` (and learn to use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger). If your C++ code base is big (e.g. several hundred thousands lines of C++) consider writing your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to generate automatically  some C++ code for serialization or printing routines.

> Convert Array in C++ to String

A possibility might be to use a semi-standardized textual representation like [JSON](https://json.org/) or [YAML](https://yaml.org/) (perhaps with databases like [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) or [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/)). Both have [open source](https://opensource.org/) libraries in C++ which could be helpful.

See also the [s11n](http://www.s11n.net/) serialization library.

Comment: An example would have been more helpful to OP, who is already expressing their awareness of the distinction between Java and C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean an array of characters, you can use something like what follows

```
std::vector arr {'a', 'b', 'c'};//the array
std::string str{arr.cbegin(), arr.cend()};//the generated string
```

Working example

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::vector arr {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    std::string str{arr.cbegin(), arr.cend()};
    std::cout << str;

}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/Mx6q1K)

Comment: std::vector requires a template argument, this probably would not compile

Comment: @WARhead, You can leave that to be deduced in C++17.

Comment: @tadman and WARhead. Please google CTAD. That is in C++ since 17.